# simplification in Z3

Tags: z3

```
(declare-datatypes () ((SE BROKEN ON OFF)))
(declare-const s SE)
(declare-const a Int)
(simplify (or (= s ON) (= s OFF) (= s BROKEN)))
(simplify (and (> a 0) (> a 1)))
```

The result is:

```
(or (= s ON) (= s OFF) (= s BROKEN))
(and (not (<= a 0)) (not (<= a 1)))
```

But the expected result was:

```
1
> a 1
```

Is it possible to simplify such expressions (the combinations of such expressions) in Z3?
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `simplify` command is just a bottom-up rewriter. It is fast, but will fail to simplify expressions such as the ones in your post. Z3 allows users to define their own simplification strategies using tactics. They are described in [this article](https://leodemoura.github.io/files/smt-strategy.pdf), and the Z3 tutorials ([Python](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/strategies) and [SMT 2.0](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies)). The following posts also have additional information:

- [t>=1 or t>=2 => t>=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507360/t-1-or-t-2-t-1)
- [Asymmetric behavior in ctx-solver-simplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618192/asymmetric-behavior-in-ctx-solver-simplify)
- [what's the difference between "simplify" and "ctx-solver-simplify" in z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809034/whats-the-difference-between-simplify-and-ctx-solver-simplify-in-z3)

The first query in your example can be simplified using the tactic `ctx-solver-simplify` (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/SlpqN)).

```
(declare-datatypes () ((SE BROKEN ON OFF)))
(declare-const s SE)
(declare-const a Int)
(assert (or (= s ON) (= s OFF) (= s BROKEN)))
(assert (and (> a 0) (> a 1)))
(apply ctx-solver-simplify)
```

The command `apply` applies the tactic `ctx-solver-simplify` over the set of assertions, and displays the resulting set of goals. Note that, this tactic is way more expensive than the command `simplify`.

Comment: Leo, could you please compare this Simplify() with the ability of popular compiler optimization? Is this similar, or different in ability? I mean is there some optimization that Simplify() can do, but compiler cannot, and vice versa? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is hard to compare. Most compilers have to deal with side-effects, aliasing, etc. The objective is also different, compilers are trying to produce efficient code. `Simplify()` is trying to produce a formula/expression that is (hopefully) easier to solve.

Comment: It's right, but it could be simpler again)

`(goals
(goal
  (not (<= a 1))
  :precision precise :depth 1)
)`

Comment: The another example is:
    `(declare-datatypes () ((SE BROKEN ON OFF)))`
    `(declare-fun x (SE) SE)`
    `(assert (or (= (x ON) ON) (= (x ON) OFF) (= (x ON) BROKEN)))`
    `(apply ctx-solver-simplify)`


It returns empty set of goals. Is it way to simplify such expressions?

Comment: It actually returns one goal: the empty goal `(goal :precision precise :depth 1)` Note that the empty goal is equivalent to `true`. That is, it is always satisfiable. We say it is trivially satisfiable.