# Z3; Simplify with if-then-else

Tags: z3

Is there a way to simplify the following expression to "6 < var"?
According to Z3, these expressions are equivalent but simplification does not produce the latter.
I have tried the three parameters since they seem to be related to if-then-else but this also did not help.

```
(declare-fun var () Int)
(simplify
    (exists ((bx Int))
        (and
        (exists ((byX Int))
          (ite (> bx 5) (= byX 0) (&& (> bx 2) (= byX (+ byX 4)))))
        (= bx (+ var 1))
        (> var 6)
        )
      )
  :push_ite_arith true
  :pull_cheap_ite true
  :ite_extra_rules true
)
      
(assert
    (not
      (iff 
        (exists ((bx Int))
            (and
            (exists ((by Int))
              (ite (> bx 5) (= by 0) (&& (> bx 2) (= by (+ by 4)))))
            (= bx (+ var 1))
            (> var 6)
            )
          )
        (< 6 var)
      )
    )
)
(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in general, no.

Z3's simplifications and what you would consider "simple" are typically not the same, and it works more or less as a black-box. It won't produce output like what you would get from a symbolic math package or alike: The simplifications are more geared towards making the input "simpler" for further solving; not for "presenting it back to the user" purpose.

You can find many similar questions on stack-overflow, see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bz3%5D+simplify and in particular this answer from Leo: [simplification in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057349/simplification-in-z3)